# Python - Spark - RDDs date convert

Tags: python, apache-spark, datetime, pyspark, rdd

It's possible to convert a RDD element in datetime without transforming the RDD into DataFrame?

I'm trying a lot of approaches but I'm not getting lucky...

```
data.sortBy(lambda l: to_date(l[-2])).collect()
data.sortBy(lambda l: Date.valueOf(l[-2])).collect()
data.sortBy(lambda l: datetime(l[-2])).collect()
```

There exists a way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sortBy` can only change the order of elements in an `RDD`, not their contents. In order to actually get the return values of any one of your datetime conversion functions, you'll have to use `map` instead:

```
data.map(lambda l: datetime(l[-2])).collect()
```